# Iteraciones con For para datos Csv

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, csv, datos

Estoy realizando iteraciones con un ciclo for para datos de un archivo csv. Utilizo una columna específica la cual es "g1" para las iteraciones de manera como se indica en el código que corresponde a esta parte. `F=-m*(df.columns[2:3])`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

Data='elcentro_earthquake_1940.csv' #es el nombre del archivo de texto plano
df = pd.read_csv(Data, sep="[;]", engine='python', header=none)
columnas=['t', 'g', 'g1']

dt=0.02
t=np.arange(0,31.18,0.02)
m=1 #[Kg]
zeta=0.01
Tn=1.2 #[s]
wn=(2*np.pi)/Tn
k=m*(wn**2)
wd=wn*(np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))

##Método Piecewise exact

A=(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*(((zeta/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))*np.sin(wd*dt))+np.cos(wd*dt)))
B=(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*((np.sin(wd*dt))/wd))
c1=(((((1-(2*(zeta**2)))/(wd*dt))-(zeta/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2)))*np.sin(wd*dt))-((1+((2*zeta)/(wn*dt)))*np.cos(wd*dt)))
C=(1/k)*(((2*zeta)/(wn*dt))+(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*(c1)))
D=(1/k)*(1 - ((2*zeta)/(wn*dt)) + (np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*(((((2*(zeta**2))-1)/(wd*dt))*np.sin(wd*dt))+(((2*zeta)/(wn*dt))*np.cos(wd*dt)))))

a=(-np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt))*((wn/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))*np.sin(wd*dt))
b=(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt))*(np.cos(wd*dt)-((zeta/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))*np.sin(wd*dt)))
c=(1/k)*((-1/dt)+(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*((((wn/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))+(zeta/(dt*(np.sqrt(1-zeta**2)))))*np.sin(wd*dt))+((1/dt)*np.cos(wd*dt)))))
d=(1/(k*dt))*(1-(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*(((zeta/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))*np.sin(wd*dt))+np.cos(wd*dt))))


F=-m*(df.columns[2:3])
u = np.zeros(len(t))
up = np.zeros(len(t))

for  i in range(0,len(t)-1):
    u[i+1]= A*u[i] + B*up[i]+ C*F[i] + D*F[i+1]
    up[i+1]= a*u[i] + b*up[i] +c*F[i] + d*F[i+1]
```

Sin embargo tengo el siguiente error. line 49, in 
u[i+1]= A*u[i] + B*up[i]+ C*F[i] + D*F[i+1].TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'. Nose qué esta mal o como debo modificar el código. El objetivo es graficar u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay un problema con el formato de los números y por eso no funciona

En tu `dataframe` es visible que utilizas la coma `,` para separar decimales pero `numpy` y `pandas` utilizan el punto `.` al igual que muchas partes del mundo, por lo que tus columnas aunque parecen ser numéricas si haces `df.info()` vas a ver que son de tipo `object` y no `float64`

La solución es indicarle a `read_csv` que utilice la coma como separador para decimales

```
df = pd.read_csv(Data, sep="[;]", engine='python', decimal=",")
```

Otro problema es que cuando intentas obtener los valores de la columna "g1" únicamente filtras el `dataframe` con `df.columns[2:3]` por lo que esto devuelve los índices y no los valores de la columna, la forma correcta sería utilizar los valores, podrías hacerlo con `df['g1'].values` pero ya que estas utilizando `numpy` puedes hacerlo así

```
df['g1'].to_numpy()
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

Data='sample.csv' #es el nombre del archivo de texto plano
df = pd.read_csv(Data, sep="[;]", engine='python', decimal=",")

columnas=['t', 'g', 'g1']

dt=0.02
t=np.arange(0,31.18,0.02)

m=1 #[Kg]
zeta=0.01
Tn=1.2 #[s]
wn=(2*np.pi)/Tn
k=m*(wn**2)
wd=wn*(np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))

##Método Piecewise exact

A=(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*(((zeta/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))*np.sin(wd*dt))+np.cos(wd*dt)))
B=(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*((np.sin(wd*dt))/wd))
c1=(((((1-(2*(zeta**2)))/(wd*dt))-(zeta/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2)))*np.sin(wd*dt))-((1+((2*zeta)/(wn*dt)))*np.cos(wd*dt)))
C=(1/k)*(((2*zeta)/(wn*dt))+(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*(c1)))
D=(1/k)*(1 - ((2*zeta)/(wn*dt)) + (np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*(((((2*(zeta**2))-1)/(wd*dt))*np.sin(wd*dt))+(((2*zeta)/(wn*dt))*np.cos(wd*dt)))))

a=(-np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt))*((wn/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))*np.sin(wd*dt))
b=(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt))*(np.cos(wd*dt)-((zeta/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))*np.sin(wd*dt)))
c=(1/k)*((-1/dt)+(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*((((wn/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))+(zeta/(dt*(np.sqrt(1-zeta**2)))))*np.sin(wd*dt))+((1/dt)*np.cos(wd*dt)))))
d=(1/(k*dt))*(1-(np.exp(-zeta*wn*dt)*(((zeta/np.sqrt(1-zeta**2))*np.sin(wd*dt))+np.cos(wd*dt))))


F=-m*(df['g1'].to_numpy())
u = np.zeros(len(t))
up = np.zeros(len(t))

for  i in range(0,len(t)-1):
    u[i+1]= A*u[i] + B*up[i]+ C*F[i] + D*F[i+1]
    up[i+1]= a*u[i] + b*up[i] +c*F[i] + d*F[i+1]
```

Comment: Muy buena tu respuesta, es un gran aporte.